# What determines the event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm only a beginner so ,my question might sound a bit stupid or basic. 
I learn programming in asp.net, therefore I see a lot of functions activated by events. Yet, I didn't find anything in the code nor in the type signature that defines which event activates the function. 
So, in functions like `public void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)`, where are the code lines that determine what event will make the function to start? Does it have any relation to the function's name? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.Net 1.1, we used to have the following system generated code in every code behind files.

```
public class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
   // ----- System generated code
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Name;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox Email;

   public Default() 
   {
         Page.Init += new System.EventHandler(Page_Init);
   }
   // ----- System generated code

   private void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
   {

   }
}
```

It basically registers method to page event. They are nothing but just make the code behind file dirty.

Start from ASP.Net 2, they moved the system generated code to designer file, and code behind file becomes clean and easy read.

```
public class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{           
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
   {     
   }
   -- OR --
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
   {
      base.OnLoad(e);
   }
}
```

> where are the code lines that determine what event will make the
>   function to start?

ASP.Net uses **conversion over configuration** approach to register events. It means, you can name a **Protected** method with following event name, and the page will know how to attach those event. For example, **Page_Init**, **Page_Load** and **Page_PreRender**

In addition, you can override those events explicit if you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Functions like Page_Load are called by ASP.NET in a particular order. You cannot configure which will fire first.  The idea is that you override the ones you need to fire your code in the particular order you need.

Here is the [MSDN Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) information which talks about which event can be overridden and what order they go in.